# Upgrading from 19.04 to 19.10 has hung up

Tags: upgrade, 19.04, 19.10

Got notification on Twitter of 19.10 upgrade available. Clicked link and everything seemed to go ok until 'Installing the Upgrades - applying changes'.
It has been stuck on this for over 6 hours. How do I get out of this? 19.04 seems to be working ok.

Comment: Yes - following Ubuntu group

Comment: https://t.co/BvYLmOsQRi

Comment: My upgrade got stuck after installing chromium. The configuration wizard became unresponsive and when I closed it the upgrade continued.

Comment: I had an upgrade take over 10 hours.  Re-installs are far quicker which is why many just backup & start fresh (then restore what they want). I always upgrade at terminal so I can monitor & explore what's occurring, but at 6 hours - I'd suggest still wait (two I did took longer than 6 hours).

Comment: I tried to kill the process (eoan) but it wouldn't let me. I'll let it run overnight, and if it's still the same in the morning I'll pull the plug.

Comment: Did a normal restart and 19.04 started ok. Asked me if I wanted to upgrade to 19.10 during login. Will try again later

Comment: Update - gave up on upgrading to 19.10 and carried on with 19.04 for a couple of weeks because I was busy with other stuff. Then one fine morning turned on my laptop and there was the 19.10 weasel (or is it an otter? or a pine marten? or a mink?). 19.10 has been running just fine since then.